# what happens when a user changes his/her password in an environment where there are multiple domain controllers

Tags: active-directory, change-password, domaincontroller

I have heard of replication between multiple domain controllers. but what if a user wants to change her/his password. it should be reflected immediately right? please explain the workflow

Answer (score 0):

The full process is described here: [Password Change and Conflict Resolution Functionality in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/225511/password-change-and-conflict-resolution-functionality-in-windows)

In short: password changes are replicated immediately.